# download file from qwebkit at pyqt

Tags: python, qt, webkit, pyqt

all. I use qwebkit pyqt4 for implementation of the browser. I have a trivial code to render the page. I can surf the web sites, but i can't download anything from it.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os, sys, urllib.request
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

if __name__ == '__main__':
    login_url = "http://google.com"

    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    frame = view.page().mainFrame()
    view.load(QUrl(login_url))
    view.show()
    app.exec_()
```

What is needed to supplement the code that you could download files from links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect a handler to the [downloadRequested](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#downloadRequested) signal of the webview's [page](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html#page), and then use the page's [networkAccessManager](http://developer.qt.nokia.com/doc/qt-4.8/qwebpage.html#networkAccessManager) to process the request.