# Converting a django app to desktop app using pyqt webkit

Tags: django, pyqt4, qtwebkit

I created a web app using django. However, I needed a desktop app of the same so I used webkit of PyQt. The whole thing works fine except for file downloads. In my web app the server serves downloadable files at several places. However, when clicking the button that is supposed to trigger the download in the desktop version of the application, nothing happens.

```
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView()
web.load(QUrl("http://localhost:8000/home"))
#web.page().setForwardUnsupportedContent(True)
#web.page().unsupportedContent.connect(save_file_callback)
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: This may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9194094/download-file-from-qwebkit-at-pyqt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
web = QWebView(loadFinished=load_finished)
web.load(QUrl("http://localhost:8000/home"))
web.page().setForwardUnsupportedContent(True)
web.page().unsupportedContent.connect(save_file_callback)
web.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())

def save_file_callback(reply):
    try:
        with urllib.request.urlopen(reply.url().toString()) as response:
            with open('downloaded_file.ext', 'wb') as f:
                f.write(response.read())
            except Exception as e:
                QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Saving Failed!', str(e), QMessageBox.Ok)

def load_finished(reply):
    if not reply:
        QMessageBox.critical(None, 'Error!', 'An error occurred trying to load the page.', QMessageBox.Ok)
```

I haven't tested the code but this should get you on the right path. The code is borrowed from my recent project which runs Django projects inside webview as desktop applications - https://github.com/awecode/django-runner

Comment: can you please explain the arguments given to save_file_callback? I am getting this error: TypeError: save_file_callback() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

My django code is:

arg2="pathtofile/result321.py"
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(arg2))
response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="result.py"'
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(arg2)
return response

Comment: @Code_aholic try with the updated code. Like I said, I haven't tested, I may have left an issue or two in the code.

Comment: Thanks! Works great.... I just had to change the code a bit to use urllib2 insted of urllib. :)

Comment: Since you have done this thing, I needed one more help. Is it possible to prevent my desktop app from going to the error page whever an error occurs and instead just pop a message saying an 'error occured try again' while staying on the same page. (That error page gives it away that it actually is a webapp rendered as dektop app)

Comment: See the updated code. Again, the code's untested, you might have to make fixes yourself.